# blazeds increase concurrent user count by using servlet 3.0 and nio server

Tags: blazeds, nio, tomcat7

i am developing a turn based multiplayer game with flex and blazeds.
Problem is that i read that the blazeds can handle only hundereds of concurrent users,but this can be increased by using nio server like jetty 7 and servlet 3.0.

does Tomcat 7 supports nio? and i wonder if i can increase concurrent user count by using tomcat 7and  blazeds to a few thousands.

Any clue or help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Do not worry yet about performance. If your game will be successful you will be able to afford the better technical solution. If not, it will not matter if you can handle 1000 or 1000000 requests.

However, related to your question - you may be able to increase the number of concurrent users by doing server related tunings (like stack size, increase the size of the thread pool).

There a couple of solutions implementing Servlet 3.0 (NIO), but you will have to write your own BlazeDS NIO endpoint - so it does not work out of the box.

Edit:

Using the NIO Jetty connector by can be a good idea...but the first thing which should be done is building and testing a valid performance scenario. For example if you plan to support 10000 connected users and to push 1 msg/sec you need to write stress test for that. After that, you can experiment using various connectors/configurations.

There is one tool created by Adobe which can help you with performance testing - it's located [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/pdfs/data_services_portfolio.pdf) (take a look at the attachments of Adobe LiveCycle Data Services 3 ES2 Performance Brief.pdf). It contains instructions how to configure/run the stress tool. If you cannot manage to run it let me know

Just to give you an example, on my machine (i7 Q820 8gb ram), using the stress tool I was able to handle 10000 connected users.

Comment: We are developing a game that has currently thousands of users and our client want to renew the game with flex.That is why hundereds of users not enough and i am trying to find a solution.Anyway i am open for any suggestion and help.

Comment: Give me a couple of days and I'll post something

Comment: I found that with jetty-blazeds.jar which consists asynchronous-endpoint class we can implement what we need but i have not configured it properly yet.But logic is simple define and end point with jetty asynchronous endpoint and if you are working with a non-jetty server you have to add a filter to web.xml to let jetty-continous.jar to handle requests. Anyway still researching for a clean solution.